Best Approach to Automatically Notify Users of Dependency Updates Between Two Repositories on GitHub
I have two repositories, A and B. Repository B has a build-time dependency on Repository A (specifically, it uses a Dockerfile base image from Repository A). While it's not mandatory for users of Repository B to immediately consume updates from Repository A, I want to automatically notify them about new releases in Repository A through GitHub pull requests. Should I implement this as a dependent bot or as a cron job in Repository B? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
